# How to report "Business Interest Expense" in California Tax Form 540NR Schedule CA

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I am reporting interest on a loan used to purchase shares in an S-Corporation as 'business interest expense' on federal form Schedule E (2012) as a Non-Passive loss, as described by the IRS here:

> How to report.   If the proceeds were used in a nonpassive trade or business activity, report the interest on Schedule E (Form 1040), line 28; enter “interest expense” and the name of the partnership or S corporation in column (a) and the amount in column (h). http://www.irs.gov/publications/p535/ch04.html

I am not a California resident, but the S-Corp does some business there and so I am filing form 540NR, but am unclear on how/where to record the 'business interest expense' in the California state forms.

1. Can I offset this interest expense against the S-Corp's ordinary business income in California?
2. If so, can I calculate the amount of interest expense to include according to percentage of the S-Corp's total ordinary income vs it's California source amounts?  That is, the company's CA source amount income was 25% of it's total income, should I include 25% of my interest expense in the California Return?
3. Where do I record this?  My best guess at this point (assuming a yes answer to #1) is to adjust the amount shown for the company's CA Sources and Credits on CA Schedule K-1(100S) by the portion of the interest determined using the method from #2 and put the result in box 17e of Schedule CA (540NR): 'CA Amounts' from 'Rental...S Corporations, etc..'

This approach seems strange to me though because the amount of that adjustment won't be recorded anywhere (except on Schedule E of my federal return, and even there, in a larger amount not showing the adjustment for the "CA portion" of the interest expense.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a situation when a consultation with a EA working with S-Corporations in California, CA-licensed CPA or tax preparer (California licenses tax preparers as well) is in order. I'm neither of those, and my answer is not a tax advice of any kind.

You're looking at schedule CA line 17 (see [page 42 in the 540NR booklet](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2012/12_540nrbk.pdf)). The instructions refer you to [form 3885A](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2012/12_3885a.pdf). You need to read the instructions carefully. California is notorious for [not conforming to the Federal tax law](http://www.caltax.org/MEMBER/digest/apr97/apr97-6.htm). Specifically, to the issue of the interest attributable to investment in S-Corp, I do not know if CA conforms. I couldn't find any sources saying that it doesn't, but then again - I'm not a professional. It may be that there's an obscure provision invalidating this deduction, living in California myself - I wouldn't be surprised. So I suggest hiring a CA-licensed tax preparer to do this tax return for you, at least for the first year.